# google cloud vision rest api with python django

Tags: python-2.7, django-rest-framework, google-cloud-vision

how can i use google cloud vision with python django rest api? My task is that i have a picture,i have to find similer picture from an another picture.is there any other solution to do this task?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/kshithijiyer/Image_analyzer) is a simple example app using the google cloud vision API with django. Of course it will take some adapting but it's something to get started with.